# Google Play не принимает приложение из-за уязвимостей OpenSSL

Tags: android, google-play

Всем привет!

Впервые столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Google Play не принимает новое приложение, сразу после публикации на почту приходит письмо:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для меня это показалось странным, я предпринял следующие методы:

1) Посмотрел версию OpenSSL

```
OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
```

2) Нашел libssl.so и libcrypto.so (версия 1.0.2) и интегрировал в проект
(создал папку jniLibs в /app/src/main и поместил туда .so файлы по необходимым папкам- armeabi, x86, armeabi-v7 ..)
Файлы в APK файл интегрировались, но это не помогло

3) Посмотрел сторонние библиотеки- вроде как с ними не должно быть проблем

Использую:

1) Google AppCompat v7 (24.2.0)

2) Google Design Library (24.2.0)

3) Google Play Licensing Library (посл.версия)

4) [android-gif-drawable (1.2.1)](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable)

5) [RootTools (посл.версия)](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-DeviceInformation)

6) [RootShell (после.версия)](https://github.com/Stericson/RootShell)

7) [EasyDeviceInfo (посл.версия)](https://github.com/nisrulz/easydeviceinfo)

8) [AndroidDeviceNames (посл.версия)](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidDeviceNames)

9) [DeviceInformation (после.версия)](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-DeviceInformation)

Вот я и не знаю, что и делать. Стоит все последнее (Android Studio, SDK 24), все обновлено, а как пофиксить не знаю :(

Comment: покажите как работаете с https?

Comment: @dramf с ним не работаю, проблему решил, сейчас опишу как

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте!
была подобная проблема.
Решилась переходом на HttpsURLConnection

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решилась следующим образом:
так как моя программа представляет собой системный твикер, один из пунктов твиков интернета был включение функции "Поддержка OpenVPN". В нем то и состояла проблема. В папке assets был файл openvpn, который содержал старую библиотеку OpenSSL. Удаление этого файла и этого пункта полностью помогло.